# Code snippet shortcut doesn't work everywhere

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-snippets

I have a code snippet `string.Format(@"")` with a shortcut `sf` that inserts the snippet and places the cursor in between the two double quotes.  Really convenient.  I can normally use it, of course, by just typing `sf` and hitting tab twice:

[image]

However, I've just discovered that the shortcut doesn't work in all locations.  For example, if I'm building this statement:

```
if(true) throw new FormatException() // <-- cursor is inside these parens
```

and I hit `sf`, the shortcut does not appear in the intellisense menu, and if I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, it doesn't generate the snippet.  Why?

I have tried searching for "C# code snippet shortcut sometimes doesn't work", "C# code snippet shortcut doesn't work", "visual studio code snippet sometimes doesn't work" among others, and I can't find anything useful about it.

**EDIT:** Here is the snippet definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>String.Format with @</Title>
      <Author>Rory</Author>
      <Description>
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>sf</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>anchor</ID>
          <ToolTip>
          </ToolTip>
          <Default>
          </Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp" Delimiter="$" Kind="method body"><![CDATA[string.Format(@"$selected$$end$")]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: Do any of the default snippets load the intellisense menu? Try "prop" in the same place

Comment: What does your snippet definition look like?

Comment: That's not relevant -- none of the snippets are available (see my answer to g williams comment, above)

Comment: it actually might, the Snippet's Kind property for example scopes which snippets are active where. I'd expect your snippet to be of kind `method body`

Comment: How/where did you define the code snippet?

Comment: @jessehouwing -- You're right about the snippet kind being "method body".  The other two available are "type declaration" and "method declaration", neither of which work.  Does that mean there are place you just can't use snippets?

Comment: @ThomasWeller -- Using [Snippet Designer](https://github.com/mmanela/snippetdesigner)

Comment: It depends on the kind. As I said before. You can set it to `Any` so it works anywhere. But I just created my own snippet in 2015 and 2013 and it just works.

Comment: @jessehouwing -- I've edited the question to include the snippet XML.  How does it compare to the one that works for you?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171418.aspx) the Kind attribute determines where you can use the snippet - you have specified "method body" and you should probably specify "any"

Answer (score 1):

I just created and tested (in VS2013 and VS2015) my own version of your snippet and it works as expected:

[image]

This is what it looks like:

﻿

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>SnippetFile1</Title>
      <Author>me@example.com</Author>
      <Description>
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>sf</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp" Delimiter="$"><![CDATA[string.Format(@"$end$")]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

For creating and editing Snippets, [the Snippet Designer is a must have](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392).

Comment: Thanks, gotta catch a train now but I'll compare this closely to my snippet (see edited question).

Comment: I even tried your snippet -- not working.  VS 2013.  BTW, I created mine with snippet designer.

Comment: Any Visual Studio updates installed, I'm on 2013 update 5? Any plugins that may interfere with snippets? Like Resharper, CodeRush or something similar?

Comment: Does the code you're editing currently parse/compile without errors? It may be that Intellisense is confused somehow.

Comment: I can't tell if I have any updates installed.  It's version 12.0.21005.1 REL.  I ran Windows Update but there was nothing for VS (and I do have it set to update all MS software, not just Windows).  The code compiles fine.  I can repro the issue very easily with just a simple new project.  I can't even use the snippet in a line like this: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(sf);`

Comment: I ran VS in safe mode (no addins) and the snippet still didn't work.

Comment: You should be on 12.0.40629.00 update 5. You can download update 5 from visualstudio.com.

Comment: Okay, I'm all up to date.  Running in safe mode.  Still not working.  No snippet shortcuts are available when the cursor is inside parens (i went through the alphabet just to be sure).